# How can I insert the UNIX timestamp into a column with my query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

How can I display the UNIX timestamp in my MySQL query? It needs to be in a format like so: 1419245107 (So no points etc) I found a function for this which is: UNIX_TIMESTAMP() but I couldn't get it to work. I want the UNIX timestamp to go into my column: registrationdate.

My query:

```
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO penguins (igloos, igloo, moderator, registrationdate, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('" + "1" + "','" + "1" + "','" + moderator + "','" + registrationdate + "','" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + UPPER(MD5('" + password + "')), '" + username + "', '"+username+"')";                console.log(insertQuery);
```

Right now, I use the following method:

```
const dateTime = new Date().getTime();
const timestamp = Math.floor(dateTime / 1000);
const registrationdate = timestamp
newUserMysql.registrationdate = registrationdate;
```

This works, but it does not update the timestamp.

How does this actually work?

Comment: Is `registrationdate` a timestamp? Then you need `FROM_UNIXTIME(1419245107)`

Comment: When the user registers, the timestamp should be automatic

Comment: Then simply use SQL's `current_timestamp` in your insert like: `...moderator + ", current_timestamp," + inventory...`

Comment: Well it didn't work for me. The format should be like: 1500202533 since my column only accepts that. This is my query:
`INSERT INTO penguins (igloos, igloo, moderator, registrationdate, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('" + "1" + "','" + "1" + "','" + moderator + "','" + ", current_timestamp," + "','" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + UPPER(MD5('" + password + "')), '" + username + "', '"+username+"')"`

Comment: Again, is `registrationdate` a timestamp?

Comment: registrationdate is a column in my database. When a user registers, the UNIX timestamp should be inserted into registrationdate. current_timestamp just added ''0'' into the column

Comment: What datatype is this column? If it's an INTEGER you need `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp)` instead.

Comment: The datatype is int(8)

Comment: Thanks for your help @dnoeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the column to include `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` This inserts the current timestamp automatically in a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column. If you are actually using an INT for this column, change it to use a DATETIME - it will make retrieval, searching, etc. MUCH easier. MySQL has great facilities built in for handling dates & times. Changing the field will use a command like:

```
ALTER TABLE `penguins` MODIFY `registrationdate` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

After changing the column, remove it from the INSERT statement as otherwise you will override the DEFAULT behavior:

```
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO penguins (igloos, igloo, moderator, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('1','1','" + moderator + "','" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + UPPER(MD5('" + password + "')), '" + username + "', '" + username + "')";
```

Comment: @JavaSherwood What did not work? The ALTER TABLE command or the correct action of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? I forgo to mention (I'll edit) that to use DEFAULT you need to NOT include the field in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Please look at the picture. It set everything to 0